# Socket.io - Manual reconnect after client-side disconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I use `node.js` and `socket.io` to create a real time web application. I will give the users full control of the socket connection, like manual disconnect and (re)connect.

```
function socket_connect()
{
    console.log('func socket_connect');
    socket = io.connect('http://url/to/the/app');
}

function socket_reconnect()
{
    console.log('func socket_reconnect');
    socket_connect();
}

function socket_disconnect ()
{
    console.log('func socket_disconnect');
    if (socket) socket.disconnect();
}
```

On client start up the `socket_connect()` function works fine, but after using `socket.disconnect()`, no new connection starts.

Comment: What do you mean with "no new connection starts"? That is does not automatically reconnect, or that when the user selects socket_connect() the new connection does not work.

Comment: The auto-reconnect works fine, thats not the problem. See my answer... Problem solved.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It works now, with socket.socket.reconnect()

```
function socket_connect()
{
    console.log('func socket_connect');
    socket = io.connect('http://url/to/the/app');
}

function socket_reconnect()
{
    console.log('func socket_reconnect');
    socket.socket.reconnect();
}

function socket_disconnect ()
{
    console.log('func socket_disconnect');
    if (socket) socket.disconnect();
}
```

Related: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/251

Answer (score 16):

You can reconnect by following client side config.

```
 // for socket.io version 1.0
io.connect(SERVER_IP,{'forceNew':true });
```

Comment: what about socket.io 2?

Answer (score 15):

If you're using Socket.io 1.0, try using the `io` manager on the socket to handle manual disconnection and reconnection.

```
// Connect to socket.io 
var socket = io.connect('url');

function manual_disconnect() {
   socket.io.disconnect();
}

function manual_reconnect() {
   socket.io.reconnect();
}
```

The reconnecting_attempt, reconnecting, reconnected and connected events on the socket should all be emitted afterwards.

Comment: irritatingly, socket.disconnect() is still available in 1.x while socket.reconnect() is not. Hence kmftzg's version is probably best