# socket.io disconnect then reconnect

Tags: socket.io

I am trying to disconnect a client, then reconnect it.

I am able to disconnect the client from the server side using `socket.disconnect();`

But i can't connect it again, is there a way to do it ?

The thing is i have a specific treatment in the client `connect callback`, and if i try to connect the client after the disconnect event, it never fires the callback, i don't understand why.

Here is a clear example:

**CLIENT**

```
var Socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');

function bind_socket(Socket) {
    Socket.on('connect', function()  {
        console.log('Socket connected !');
    });

    Socket.on('event', function(data)  {
        console.log('Receive event: '+data);
    });

    Socket.on('disconnect', function()  {
        console.log('Socket disconnected !');

        var Socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000'); //Doesn't fire the "connect" callback
        bind_socket(Socket);
        Socket.emit('event', 3);
    });
}

bind_socket(Socket);
Socket.emit('event', 1);
```

**SERVER**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('socket '+socket.id+' connect');

    socket.on('event', function(data) {
        console.log('Receive Event: '+data);
        socket.disconnect();
        this.emit('event', 2);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('socket '+this.id+' disconnect');
    });
});
```

Comment: actually I used socket.io for few months ..in development its working great but in production you will face many problems regarding CPU and memory ..switch to sockjs is more better

Comment: Yes i hope the v1.0 will come up soon (it's been more than 6 month i keep saying this...). I use socket.io for its `rooms` service, doesn't seems to exist on sockjs, but i agree it's probably a better choice regarding how `socket.io` looks abandonned...

Comment: The same here ...I am waiting version 1.0 but if you check the activites on their github page ..there are more than 500 opened issues ..sockjs is more better but less features

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is to use `Socket.socket.reconnect();`

(where `Socket` is the "original" socket returned by the connection event).

Comment: This really helped me. Especially during tests, where you have to connect and reconnect multiple times to test different events. Thanks!

Comment: This is no longer correct as of Socket.IO 2.x. Use `connect()` instead as @Qiulang mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50737936/4922436).

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Socket.io 1.0, try using the `io` manager on the socket to do `disconnect()` and `reconnect()`

See the example on [Socket.io - Manual reconnect after client-side disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023703/socket-io-manual-reconnect-after-client-side-disconnect#24700263)

Comment: This seems to be the way to go for socket.io 1.x, thank you very much! Unlike socket.disconnect(), socket.io.disconnect() triggers the disconnect handler *and* actually terminates the connection. socket.disconnect() only invokes the handler...

Answer (score 4):

If using socket 2.x just `socket.connect()` the other answers talking about `reconnect()` is not correct in 2.x

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
socket.disconnect(2);
```

(found this accidentally) - this sends different disconnect error code: 
'failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response'. and then frontend socket is trying to reconnect.

But then you run in another problem - socket connect/disconnect makes connection flood.