# Why do event listeners not respond after Socket.IO disconnect and reconnect?

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

Here is a dead simple Socket.IO v1.0 app, based on one of the examples from the official documentation.  Upon connection, the server emits a "news" event, and then nothing else happens.

```
// app.js (excluding http handler)

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    socket.emit("news", { hello: "world" });
});
```

On the client side, the receipt of the "news" event is alerted, and nothing else happens.

```
// client.js

var socket = io();
socket.on("news", function (data) {
    alert("Received news event");
});
```

When I disconnect and reconnect to my socket as follows, both the server's and the client's socket.io debug log shows the "news" event being sent and received.  However, the alert box appears only on the first connection, not on the second connection after the disconnect.

```
socket.disconnect();
socket.connect();

// alert box expected here, but does not appear
```

However, if I follow the recommendation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24700263/1407170) (which was posted just 16 hours ago) and use the `socket.io` API instead, then the alert box appears.

```
socket.io.disconnect();
socket.io.reconnect();

// alert box appears here
```

Here's my question.  What is the `io` property that seems to have appeared in v1.0?  How is the disconnect/reconnect API on `io` different from the disconnect/connect API available directly on the socket instance?