# Reconnect socket io v1.3.5

Tags: angularjs, node.js, websocket, socket.io, ejs

I built a website realtime with socket.io + NodeJs. And I have load balancing for my website. I set timeout for my website in load balancing is 60 second.
This is my code in client:

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('disconnect');
    //Reconnect
});
socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('connect');
});
```

After 60s, event disconnect is fired but I don't know how to client reconnect again. I tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023703/socket-io-manual-reconnect-after-client-side-disconnect) but not working. Anyone can help me pls? Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with just doing: `socket = io.connect("socketUrl");` again? That's how we do it.

Comment: Tks for reply. It's working. And there's another way to solve this problem?